# how to I can see users that have hidden news of my fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I have a fan page on facebook with 20k fans, I can see how many users have hidden my news/posts by their wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this. The page insights will show you the reach for your page, but it will not give explicit numbers on who has hidden your posts.

Comment: ok, so I have 20k fans but this is not true that all follow my posts, thank you